# What is the corresponding code in Qt for "string s = textBox1.text"?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

How can I read a text from "textEdit" tool of Qt gui applicatons?

I was expecting something like `QString s =  ui->textEdit->text();`

but there is no command like this.

Comment: Use `QTextEdit::toPlainText()` instead

Comment: or toHtml(), if you want richtext/html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QTextEdit` contains method:

[`QString toPlainText()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qtextedit.html#plainText-prop)

That should give you the text contained in the `QTextEdit`.